# How to get information on which "share" app was used via EasySharing Action in Android

Tags: android, socialshare

Our android app has an item view screen that can be shared socially via the android easy share action. For metrics and statistics reasons, we want to capture 
**(a)** that the user was successfully able to share the screen and not quit it before posting, and **(b)** what app, like twitter, FB, messaging etc was used to share the item.

Currently we are able to capture until the point the "share" was clicked. Now if the user exit out of the widget without sharing or share with some app, we have no way to find that. Is there a way we can capture the above information?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.